# hibernate error when executing DDL statement

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

i'm trying tro create a bank managing system with spring boot for learning purpose and i got this error
Error executing DDL "create table compte (type_cpte varchar(2) not null, code_compte varchar(255) not null, date_creation datetime, solde double precision not null, decouvert double precision, taux double precision, code_client bigint, primary key (code_compte)) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement.

i'm a beginer in spring boot and java i don't know how to fix this.

the link to my repository https://github.com/Bomt237/Gestion-Banque.git

the error message

```
Hibernate: create table compte (type_cpte varchar(2) not null, code_compte varchar(255) not null, date_creation datetime, solde double precision not null, decouvert double precision, taux double precision, code_client bigint, primary key (code_compte)) engine=MyISAM
2023-03-03 09:23:07.649  WARN 13288 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table compte (type_cpte varchar(2) not null, code_compte varchar(255) not null, date_creation datetime, solde double precision not null, decouvert double precision, taux double precision, code_client bigint, primary key (code_compte)) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table compte (type_cpte varchar(2) not null, code_compte varchar(255) not null, date_creation datetime, solde double precision not null, decouvert double precision, taux double precision, code_client bigint, primary key (code_compte)) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:581) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:526) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.sid.BanqueApplication.main(BanqueApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:763) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

the compte class

```
package org.sid.entités;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorColumn;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import lombok.ToString;
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy =InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE_CPTE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 2)
@ToString
public abstract class Compte implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String codeCompte;
    private Date dateCreation;
    private double solde;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CODE_CLIENT")
    private Client client;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "compte")
    private Collection<Operation> operations;
    public Compte() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Compte(String codeCompte, Date dateCreation, double solde, Client client) {
        super();
        this.codeCompte = codeCompte;
        this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
        this.solde = solde;
        this.client = client; 
    }
    public String getCodeCompte() {
        return codeCompte;
    }
    public void setCodeCompte(String codeCompte) {
        this.codeCompte = codeCompte;
    }
    public Date getDateCreation() {
        return dateCreation;
    }
    public void setDateCreation(Date dateCreation) {
        this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
    }
    public double getSolde() {
        return solde;
    }
    public void setSolde(double solde) {
        this.solde = solde;
    }
    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }
    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }
    public Collection<Operation> getOperations() {
        return operations;
    }
    public void setOperations(Collection<Operation> operations) {
        this.operations = operations;
    }
    

}
```

the extends class

```
package org.sid.entités;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

import lombok.ToString;
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CC")
@ToString
public class CompteCourant extends Compte {
    
    private double decouvert;

    public CompteCourant() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CompteCourant(String codeCompte, Date dateCreation, double solde, Client client, double decouvert) {
        super(codeCompte, dateCreation, solde, client);
        this.decouvert = decouvert;
    }

    public double getDecouvert() {
        return decouvert;
    }

    public void setDecouvert(double decouvert) {
        this.decouvert = decouvert;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DDL fired clearly shows engine confgured as 'MyISAM' it should rather be InnoDB

try with

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: i don't think this might be the problem i have similar tables in the projects wich has been generated